# Parsing inconsistently formatted text data using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-processors

I'm having difficulty parsing text from a spreadsheet. I have a spreadsheet with hundreds of records that look similar to the below example (this is all in one cell):

```
7431340 03 POOLS E TECHNOLOGIES INC 90 NEW ENGLAND DRIVE 16 0.00 6,900 7,060
```

I need to parse each of the following into separate cells:

```
[7431340] [03 POOLS E TECHNOLOGIES INC] [90 NEW ENGLAND DRIVE] [7,060]
```

or as it would appear in an Excel sheet

[image: End result in Excel, showing first number in column A, number plus company name in column B, street address in column C, and last number in row in column D]

The issue I'm having is that the data is inconsistent for each record. More examples:

```
7170258 111 HARBOR POINT OWNER LLC 115 TOWNE STREET 16 0.00 189,200 196,730
4469000 4 KIDZ INC 62 SOUTHFIELD AVENUE 16 0.00 3,000 9,500
6369875 3 HERMANOS LLC 912 EAST MAIN STREET 16 0.00 4,640 4 640
```

I would like to avoid as much manual manipulation as possible, but I fear I may be out of luck.

How do I parse the data when its format is not consistent?

Comment: The one example you provided throws away two numeric values after the street address; will that be consistent? Looks like rule one would be to pull the first numeric string into a cell, rule two is to take the numbers immediately thereafter and add to the company name to go into a second cell, rule three is to move the address into a third cell, and rule four takes the last comma-formatted value into a fourth cell, discarding three numeric values between it and the end of the street address. Is that correct?

Comment: As @K7AAY points out, you haven't explained the rules for deciding how the data is to be split into the four cells. Please edit your question to add this information. I few more examples would also help.

Comment: @K7AAY Parsing the first numeric and last numeric string is always consistent, which is the easy part. The real issue I am having is parsing out the two pieces of information in the middle. That is where the inconsistencies lie.

Comment: As I wrote, if your data is truly representative, my solution should work.  If it is not, you will need to provide examples of where it fails, in order to see if there is some usable pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If your examples are truly representative, then there is a pattern which is amenable to extraction by using Regular Expressions.  This can be implemented in Excel using VBA.

Pattern:

- Start of string
- Series of digits followed by a space
- Substring that starts with one or more digits, and contains no other digits
- a second Substring that starts with one or more digits, and contains no other digits
- multiple space-separated digit-comma groups, with an optional comma (return the last one)

All of your examples show that pattern.
Here is a user defined function that will handle that:

```
Option Explicit
Function extrAddressPart(sAddr As String, lPart As Long)
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Const sPat As String = "^(\d+)\s+(\d+\D+)\s+(\d+\D+)\s+.*\s+([\d,]+)$"

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = sPat
    .MultiLine = True
    .Global = False
    If .Test(sAddr) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(sAddr)
        extrAddressPart = MC(0).submatches(lPart - 1)
    End If
End With
End Function
```

[image]

Of course, if your example is not truly representative, then this solution will not work.

Comment: Excel cannot do regular expressions in Search and Replace? I use LibreOffice Calc and it can.

Comment: Better add some examples that how to  use the Function,,, and one more OP has mixed delimiter, will this work for all!

Comment: @RajeshS What problems do you have using the function?  And in his examples, the only character delimiter is a `<space>`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, check my solution there I've show how to use the Function, `=ReplaceAndSplit(A2,",")` . Personally I don't have any  issue but for others it may ☺so that I've written !

Comment: @RajeshS In your solution, you mention various delimiters. The only delimiter in the examples is a <space> and when that is used, your UDF merely splits the string into individual words.  Look at my screenshot for a better understanding of what his examples look like.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, Yes true, I've shown how to handle with various Delimiter since OP has sentences within `[ ]` , `Comma` & `Space` too.

Comment: @RajeshS But the ONLY delimiter he uses in his examples is a space, and your UDF just splits the string into individual words.  (The commas in his example are thousands separators; and the brackets are merely indicators as to how he wants the string parsed).  Perhaps YOU should be showing how your solution will work on HIS examples, perhaps with a screenshot as I did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84180/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-ron-rosenfeld).

Answer (score 0):

**Since you are dealing with Multiple Delimiters so  in that case I would like to suggest you two possible solutions.**

**Solution 1 (VBA Macro):**

```
Function ReplaceAndSplit(ByRef Text As String, ByRef DelimChars As String) As String()
    Dim DelimLen As Long, Delim As Long
    Dim strTemp As String, Delim1 As String, Arr() As String, ThisDelim As String
    strTemp = Text
    Delim1 = Left$(DelimChars, 1)
    DelimLen = Len(DelimChars)
    For Delim = 2 To DelimLen
        ThisDelim = Mid$(DelimChars, Delim, 1)
        If InStr(strTemp, ThisDelim) <> 0 Then _
            strTemp = Replace(strTemp, ThisDelim, Delim1)
    Next
    ReplaceAndSplit = Split(strTemp, Delim1)
End Function
```

**How it works:**

1. Enter this code as a Module along with the 
   Sheet.
2. Write this Formula in desire cell then fill it 
   Right till needed, press `F2` and finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

   `{=ReplaceAndSplit(A2,",")}`

**Note:**

1. `","` is for `Comma` as Delimiter.
2. It should be `" "` for `Space`.
3. `"[ ]"` for `Brackets`.

**Solution 2 (Excel Formula):**

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",",REPT(" ",256)),(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*255+1,255)),"]","")
```

**Note:**

*You need to edit this part of the Formula according to the Delimiter before you execute it, for example,*

1. `SUBSTITUTE($A1,","` for `Comma` as Delimiter.
2. `SUBSTITUTE($A1," "` for `Space` as Delimiter.
3. `SUBSTITUTE($A1,"["` for `Bracket` as 
    Delimiter.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding his examples.  His second line, with the brackets `[  ]` is showing how he wants the first line split into cells.  And the commas are a thousands separator; not a delimiter.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld,, above it OP has written,, `I need to parse each of the following into separate cells:` and OP wants to place data within `[ ]` into separate cells ☺

Comment: Well, one of us is clearly not understanding his examples.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld may be, so better let the OP decide ☺

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You are correct in your interpretation. The brackets represent the cell. I thought that would be a good visual representation.

Comment: Added a screenshot snip of an Excel sheet to show how the example would appear, based on OP's description.